# Servlet NO REDIRIGE

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Buen día, lo que pasa es que tengo un servlet que no me redirige a un .JSP llamado "buscar" sino a otro que tengo creado llamado "error.jsp". Esto solo pasa si agrego el If(); que mostraré a continuación, si lo quito si me redirige a la página, alguna idea?

```
   String accion = request.getParameter("accion");

   if(accion.equals("comentar")){
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String comentarios = request.getParameter("comentario");

        ComentariosPOJO usuario = new ComentariosPOJO();
        ComentariosDAO dao = new ComentariosDAO();

        usuario.setNombre(nombre);
        usuario.setComentario(comentarios);

        dao.insertar(usuario);
        response.sendRedirect("buscar.jsp");
    }else if(accion.equals("buscar")) {
        String nombre1 = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String comentarios2 = request.getParameter("comentario");
        ComentariosPOJO usuario2 = new ComentariosPOJO();
        usuario2.setNombre(nombre1);
        usuario2.setComentario(comentarios2);

        ComentariosDAO dao2 = new ComentariosDAO();
        try{
            List lista = dao2.buscar(usuario2);
            session.setAttribute("comentarios",lista);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        response.sendRedirect("buscar.jsp");
    }else{
        response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
    }
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: La única explicación es que `accion` no es ni "comentar" ni "buscar"

Comment: @G. Tary Lograste resolver el error